# Using Highcharts with IE 11 from ES5 folder but it crashes

Tags: highcharts, ecmascript-5

I try to run Highcharts with IE11 but it crashes

I load Highcharts from ES5 folder as told in the documentation.

IE11 devtool console indicates that the Highcharts es5 code not seem to be valid ES5.

Is there a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It's difficult to say what is wrong without seeing your code or any example. Make sure the issue is not caused by Internet Explorer 11 itself, as it is no longer supported. Please provide some additional information, such as the version of Highcharts, whether you are using any wrappers, and if you are encountering any errors. If possible, please try to reproduce your issue in an online demo. Regards

Comment: We've found the error. The ES5 code has been constructed wrong using a ES6 type of object {d} instead of {d:d}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've found the error. The ES5 code has been constructed wrong using a ES6 type of object {d} instead of {d:d}.

It has been addressed by the library owners. In the meanwhile we've corrected the code in the lib in our app, runs fine now.